# Match data different workbook and different order

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to match name data from 2 different worksheet and from 2 different workbook. And I'm already create macros vba. But this macros is for the data type when the data is in the same order, how if the data isn't in the same order?

**example of the name data**

```
In first workbook

Name
Andre
Renata
Marie

In second workbook

Name
Andre
Marie
Renata
```

Using my macros the result for above data is NOT MATCH. But I want the result for above data is MATCH.

**and this is my macros vba**

```
Sub matchdata_Click()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim diffs As String

        With Workbooks("A.xls").Worksheets("1")
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Workbooks("B.xlsx").Worksheets("1")
        Set rng2 = .Range("M3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For iRow = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Max(rng1.Rows.Count, rng2.Rows.Count)
        If rng1(iRow) <> rng2(iRow) Then diffs = diffs & iRow & vbLf
    Next

    If diffs <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Different name in rows:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & diffs
    Else
        MsgBox "All names match"
    End If
```

Kindly help me if you know how to do it

Comment: Why not start by sorting both ranges?

Comment: do you want to check if on the two sheet in the same row the same names are, or if on the second sheet exist the names from the first sheet?

Comment: @tretom I want to check if on the two sheet in that range that I've set have the same names even the order isn't same just like my example

Comment: @SJR I have sorting both ranges but this will work just if the data between two sheet is in the same order

Comment: @tretom sorry I dont get what you mean. Because when I run this macro it still works but just if the data in the same order

Comment: sorry I erased that comment :o) - but check my answer it might help you

Comment: Don't really understand that. If you sort both workbooks you will have Andre/Marie/Renata. What if you 4 names on one workbook and 3 on the other, should the 4th be flagged up as a difference?

Comment: yes it should be flagged up as difference too @SJR

Comment: You should provide feedback on the solution offered. If still a problem, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

a small possible solution without ranges (and the cells' coodinates can be changed according to your needs):

```
Option Explicit
Sub check()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    i = 1
    While Workbooks("A.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        j = 1
        found = False
        While Workbooks("B.xls").Sheets(2).Cells(j, 13).Value <> ""

            If Workbooks("A.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Workbooks("B.xls").Sheets(2).Cells(j, 13).Value Then found = True

            j = j + 1
        Wend

        If found = False Then
            Workbooks("A.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```